# "What is the price of the phone you bought" or "What was the price of the phone you bought"?

Tags: grammar, past-simple, present-simple

Is there any difference in meaning between the following sentences?

> What **is** the price of the phone you bought?
>
> What **was** the price of the phone you bought?

I think that the first sentence connotes that if you you go to shop and want to buy the phone the price is the same as it was when the phone was bought. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

> What is the price of the phone you bought?

This asks the current price, which may or may not be the price of the phone when it was bought.

> What was the price of the phone you bought?

This asks the price at the time it was bought.

There's no guarantee the price stayed the same between these two times, and you can't figure out if it is the same by only asking one question.

If a person asks "What is the price?" when they clearly meant "What was the price?" it is a sign that they are more comfortable with the present tense, and are hoping you can guess (from context) what tense they meant.